# Access parent class properties from child class that have been set by parent constructor in PHP

Tags: php, class, properties, parent

OK, I'm having a bit of a problem. Here's the scenario:
I need to be able to get the constructor of test2 to be able to access the class property test that is inside main_class that has been set by main_class' constructor. I'm not sure how to get it to work, and I need the system to work like exactly like this. Now, this WOULD work if I set the class variable in the code, like this `var test = "hello";` in the class definition, but of course in this case, main_class::test is set by it's constructor and is not a "var", so it doesn't work.

Here is a highly simplified version of my code:

index.php:

```
<?php

class main_class
{
    private $test2;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test2 = array();
        include("./test1.php");
        $var_name = "test";
        $this->$var_name = new test1();
    }

    protected function do_include()
    {
        include("./test2.php");
        $this->test2["test2"] = new test2();
    }
}

$test = new main_class();

?>
```

test1.php:

```
class test1 extends main_class
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->do_include();
    }
}

?>
```

test2.php:

```
class test2 extends test1
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r($this->test);
    }
}

?>
```

With this code, I get this error:
    Notice: Undefined property: test2::$test

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How exactly one makes a decision on what should be in `$var_name`?

Comment: @OIS that does nothing

Comment: @raina77ow In the original function, it loads them from other files. So it needed to be this way for it to flexible.

Comment: This is impossible because you need to call the parent::__constructor() to initialize the parent class, but because your classes all intermingle so much it's an infinite loop. You need to structure your classes differently. Ideally without extending the other classes.

Comment: OK, Just to prove that it is working OK if I hard-code the property "test" of main_class as `var $test = "Hello";`, execute these files, and you will find that the output is:

index.php: http://pastebin.com/4LLT8FwY
test1.php: http://pastebin.com/1xci1sNs
test2.php: http://pastebin.com/e9ZCwcvE

You will find that the output is: http://pastebin.com/4FCxDKF0
And there are no infinite loops in sight.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that part of the problem may be that you're not calling the parent constructor in your test2 class:

```
class test2 extends test1
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r($this->test);
    }
}
```

If that line is left out, then your test2 constructor overrides the test1 constructor completely, and `$this->do_include()` is never called.

Also, remember that when you call `$this->test2["test2"] = new test2();`, you are creating a new instance of this class, which is not associated with the current one.

Just to clarify, here's the order of events:

`$test = new main_class(); // calls the constructor of main_class:`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->test2 = array();
    include("./test1.php");
    $var_name = "test";
    $this->$var_name = new test1();
}
```

Then:

`$this->$var_name = new test1(); // calls the constructor of test1:`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->do_include();
}
```

...which calls do_include() from main_class:

```
protected function do_include()
{
    include("./test2.php");
    $this->test2["test2"] = new test2();
}
```

Then:

`$this->test2["test2"] = new test2(); // calls the constructor of test2:`

```
public function __construct()
{
    print_r($this->test);
}
```

This creates a *new* object, and all you're doing in its constructor is printing a variable ($test) that does not exist yet...because you haven't done anything to create it.

Comment: Hi thanks, I did check, $this->do_include() is being called OK without the `parent::__construct()` bit, because I made it print out the word "Hello" and guess what, it printed.

Also, just to clarify, if I hard code the variable into the class definition, like so: `var test = "hello";` it works just fine. I just need a way for the class test2 to be able to access it without it having to be hard coded, i.e. `$this->$var_name = new test1()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Because if you look, it instantiates test1 and test2 separately within main_class, but they are still all connected. As proved above.

Comment: But they're all creating _different_ objects. They're connected only in that an instance of `main_class` knows about the child instances of `test1` and `test2`. When you construct `test2`, it knows nothing about the parent. If _both_ your `test1` and `test2` classes called their parent constructors, then `main_class`'s constructor would be called, and `main_class::$test` would have a value. Without that, your `test2` constructor is trying to print a variable that just doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, Just to prove that it is working OK if I hard-code the property "test" of main_class as `var $test = "Hello";`, execute these files, and you will find that the output is:

index.php: http://pastebin.com/4LLT8FwY
test1.php: http://pastebin.com/1xci1sNs
test2.php: http://pastebin.com/e9ZCwcvE

You will find that the output is: http://pastebin.com/4FCxDKF0
And there are no infinite loops in sight.

Comment: And to clarify, when I said that `$this->do_include()` was never being called, I meant that it isn't being called during the construction of a `test2` instance. It is, however, being called during the construction of a `test1` instance, as I outlined in the order of events. This is why you're seeing output when you echo from it.

Comment: OK, so how come test2 can access `main_class::$test` if test is hard-coded into the class definition like this: `var $test = "Hello";`.

I'm kind of confused now, I'm getting contradicting answers from different people.

Comment: And yes, I would absolutely expect it to work fine if you defined a `public` or `protected` variable in the parent `main_class`. Your problem is that you're creating a new member variable at runtime in the parent constructor, and your child constructors aren't calling that parent constructor. So that new member variable is never created.

Comment: OK, I think I see. Thanks for your patience and guidance.